# how to write an Elasticsearch query having multiple conditions

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elk, elasticsearch-query

Need help constructing an ES query. Here's an example of the raw JSON of the documents:

```
{
  "user_uuid": 1234,
  "keywords": "apple",
  "@timestamp": "2020-01-15",
},
{
  "uuid": 1234,
  "keywords": "google",
  "@timestamp": "2020-01-21",
},
{
  "uuid": 9876,
  "keywords": "youtube",
  "@timestamp": "2020-01-25",
}
```

Here is an example requirement:

```
{
    "search_groups":[
        {
            "keywords": [
                "google",
                "microsoft",
                "tesla"
            ],
            "time_range": 2020-01-17 - 2020-01-22
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "apple",
                "youtube",
                "spotify"
            ],
            "time_range": 2020-01-10 - 2020-01-25
        },

    ]
}
```

Here is what I want to achieve based on the above requirement:

I should be able to get the *unique user_uuid* which satisfies all the search groups. That is,

```
Get unique uuids where both conditions are true:
  (
    (keywords should match one of "google" OR "microsoft" OR "tesla")
    and
    (@timestamp must be between "2020-01-17" and "2020-01-22")
  )
  AND
  (
    (keywords should match one of "apple" OR "youtube" OR "spotify")
    and
    (@timestamp must be between "2020-01-10" and "2020-01-25")
  )
```

*1234* is the user_uuid which satisfies this query.

How do I construct this as an ES query?

Comment: Look over [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and attempt to construct your query. If it does not work, share your attempt here and the community can help you fix it. (I linked to 5.5 doc, because you tagged the question w/ 5 but change the doc version to whichever you are using specifically)

Comment: okay, let me try and get back. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @ekmcd here is the query I tried:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kE4uwA9hP92EOTuImVl4WTOdhcaS93lwq2Auy03pwr8/edit

Comment: @ekmcd as shown in the word doc link I shared above, if I try querying with single condition, both my queries work fine. but If I combine them, it does not. How do I find the intersection of both the queries? please advice